# Normal distribution result with weird result

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given this question in class:

$f(x) = -5x^2 + 30x -49$

It looked like a fairly normal quadratic equation at first glance until I put it into the quadratic formula and got the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

This was the output:

$3-0.89i$

$3+0.89i$

What exactly does the $i$ mean, and is this answer correct?

I was also then asked to find the vertex which I found to be:
$-b/2a  = -30/2 x -5  = 3$

then $y = -5 x 3^2 + 30 x 3 - 49 = -34$

so the vertex is then $(3,-34)$.

I am not $100\%$ sure if this is right.
But I was then asked to decide if this was a minimum or maximum value of the vertex. How would I decide this?

Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, does this have to do with the normal distribution?

Comment: woops! lol - sorry its late

Answer (score 2):

Your quadratic equation $f(x) = $ doesn't not have any real solutions. $f(x) < 0$ for all real numbers $x$. See the plot of $f$ on [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5x%5E2%20%2b%2030x%20-49)

The equation does, however, have solutions in the *complex plane*. $i$ stands for $\sqrt{-1}$, which obviously doesn't exist as a real number, but you can *add* it to the real numbers to extend the real line to the complex plane.

Comment: For some reason I have always disliked $i$ being called not real, I mean we know what that means, but in english terms, $1$ is no more "real" than $i$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Fighting established vocabulary isn't particularly helpfull here, I think. You need to have *some* name for $\mathbb{R}$, and *real numbers* isn't the worst choice possible.

Comment: I am not fighting over vocabulary. I used the word real in my answer too. I am just saying that people most often think that imaginary implies $i$ doesn't exist.(so left a comment for the OP) I mean that, initially I looked at it as $\sqrt{-1}$ was *called* $i$(another mistake here) and that we were only studying properties that would be true *if* it existed. It was a long time before anyone explained why actually studying the properties of something that doesn't(?) exist makes sense.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Hm, I think I get your point. Guess I've gotten so used to thinking in terms of *consistency* instead of *existance* that I forgot how much confusion there is about questions like "Does $i$ *really* exist?". BTW, my standard answer to people who ask me "Hey, you studied math, now tell me, does $i$ really exist?" is to say "If you don't believe that $i$ exists, what about $\pi$?" and go on by explaining that $\pi$ really is a much weirder number than $i$.

Comment: Actually, just ask them does $-1$ exist? How can *something* be less than *nothing*? :D Eventually they realize that the negative numbers came into being out of a need to represent "reverse". Like to represent debt instead of bank balance. To represent down instead of up(or the other way round), to represent left instead of right. After that you just say, what if I want to turn $90^{\circ}$ instead of a full $180$? And voila!(bonus points if you can convince them that none of the real numbers except the natural numbers exist)

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is

$$-5x^2+30x-49=0$$

$$-5\left(x^2-6x+\frac{49}{5}\right)=0$$

$$-5\left(\left(x-3\right)^2 +\frac{4}{5}\right)=0$$

As you will notice, the square is always positive, and therefore positive added to $4/5$ cannot be zero. This means that the equation has no real roots. Both roots are complex(I am assuming you know what that means)

As for the maximum minimum problem, the vertex is a maximum, since the function is maximized at $x=3$ with value $-4$

Comment: how exactly did you get the -4 ? I substituted the x=3 to get the -34 for y..

Comment: @joe you probably made an arithmetic error. $$-5(3)^2+30(3)-49=-45+90-49=-4$$